# Partial measurement can be replaced with constant overhead

Tags: quantum-algorithms, measurement

While reading the chapter on Quantum Computation (starting on page 401) of the [draft version of the Arora & Barak book](https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf) I came across exercise §4 on page 431 that reads as:

> Suppose that $f$ is computed in $T$ time by a quantum algorithm that uses a
> partial measurement in the middle of the computation, and then proceeds differently according to the result of the measurement. Show that $f$ is computable by $\mathcal{O}(T)$ elementary
> operations.
>
> (This exercise is implicitely used on page 416.)

So far I think I understand the required definitions, but unfortunately I do not see how to solve this exercise. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE.  Can you review the [principle of deferred measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Measurement_Principle)?

Comment: Check out the two examples in my answer to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15349/10480) that demonstrate deferred measurement in two important cases (measurement result used to control a quantum gate and an intermediate measurement sandwiched between two gates).